# Perl or shell - Get the number from a string variable and increment the number by 1

Tags: string, perl, shell, increment

Am writing a script in shell and I've a variable like this -

```
$ grep A41A41 file
A41A41  06
```

I want to grep a particular string combination as shown above and increment the number associated to the string (in the same line after 2 spaces) by 1. And leave rest of the file as it is (File will have some 800 rows).
**09 should become 10 and 99 should become 01.**
Also, A41A41 will be a variable and in the *for* loop the value of this variable will change in every iteration
I am doing all this in a for loop so I also need to consider performance of incrementing.

Appreciate your help in solving this problem.

Comment: Where is any variable?

Comment: Are you sure `99` + 1 should become `01` and not `00` ?

Comment: A41A41 will be a variable and in the for loop the value of this variable will change in every iteration..

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what should happen to 09 - should it become 10 or 010?

The former in Perl:

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/(A41A41\s+)([0-9]+)/sprintf "%s%02d", $1, $2 + 1/e' file
```

To get the 99 -> 01 transition, use

```
($2 + 1) % 99 || 99
```

Comment: Thanks, 09 should become 10 and 99 should become 01.

Comment: Yes, Walter. 99 + 1 should become 01.

Comment: Jens, I tried, grep -> Store number in a variable -> increment -> rewrite.
But this was very slow considering ~800 iterations and I dont feel this is the right way to do it.

Comment: `($2 + 1) % 99` -- but then we have 98 -> 00

Comment: Choroba, thanks for your script. But it made below change in the file:-
A41A41  %02
Also, can we incorporate 2 more things in this script?
I want to assign a variable to A41A41
$VARIABLE = A41A41
And
99 should become 01.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: `env key=A41A41 perl -pe 's/($ENV{key}\s+)...`

Comment: @glennjackman: `s/(\Q$ENV{key}\E\s+)...`, plus see the update on how to solve the 98 -> 00 :-)

Comment: @choroba, Sorry if this is a stupid question. but I want to put a variable there in the command instead of A41A41. because I want to use your code like this -
`for RAO_SEQ in `cat try.extract`
                        do
perl -i~ -pe 's/(VARIABLEHERE\s+)([0-9]+)/sprintf "%s%02d", $1, $2 + 1/e' try.master
done`
The for loop will re-iterate ~400 times with new variable everytime and will increment the number in try.master file. So I need to put a variable there. Also please help me incorporating below logic in the same command. cuz it can be any number from 01 to 99.
`($2 + 1) % 99 || 99`

Comment: `$ENV{var}` is the Perl way to access environment variables. `\Q...\E` will handle special characters in the values. We've shown you all you need.